# Which algorithm to use for alphabetical sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, alphabetical

A lot of sorting algorithms are based on comparisons of numbers. If I correctly understand, when we are using comparison algorithms for alphabetical sort, we compare char codes(their integer presentation) and sort depending on their values. (That's why at `ASCII` table letter `B` has a bigger code then `A`). But during this comparing we sort only by the first letter and not the whole word. When we use `db query` with `ORDER BY` we are getting sorting for the whole words. (As I understand the reason of it is db background mechanisms like indexes etc.). Also I heard about `Radix sort` (sorry, but never used it before) and as I can see it can help with alphabetical sort(maybe I'm wrong).

What algorithm is better to use for sorting by the whole words?

Not correct:

```
Adam
Aaron
Antony
```

Correct:

```
Aaron
Adam
Antony
```

And am I correct with my assumptions about the whole workflow?

Comment: What is the problem faced by other algorithms such as quicksort, heapsort?

Comment: _“But during this comparing we sort only by the first letter and not the whole word”_ – nope … if the first letters of both words are the same, then the comparison continues with the second letter, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not quite correct with the assumption about "Compare only the first letter". The algorithm is - if the first letters are the same, compare the next letter. And the next. And the next. Until either you find some letters that are different, or one of the strings runs out.

Also note that simply comparing by ASCII codes is not always enough. Sometimes you need to do a case-insensitive comparison where you consider `A` to be equal to `a`. Sometimes you need to do accent-insensitive comparison where you consider `ā` to be equal to `a`. And sometimes you need to account for crazy language shit where `ß` is equal to `ss` or worse.

My advice is - your programming language should probably have some mechanism for comparing strings. Use that. Don't roll out your own.

After that, any sorting algorithm will work. They all use one simple assumption - that you can **compare** the items that you sort. Whether they are integers, strings or complex objects, is irrelevant. As long as you can take any two objects and say "this one is bigger and this one is smaller", you're good to go.

(Note also that you need to be consistent about it. If A==B and B==C, then also you need to make sure that A==C. Similarly if A < B and B < C, then you must A < C. Etc.)

Comment: Not true, comparing ASCII is enough since there are separate ASCII codes for capital and small characters.

Comment: @vedi0boy I think their point was in ASCII A<B but a>B. So if you want it sorted [Aa]-[Zz], then just comparing ASCII values is insufficient. But if you're ok with A-Za-z, then just comparing ASCII values would work.

Comment: @KevinRak - Congratulations! You win the unofficial "necrocommenter" badge! 

Comment: @Vilx-  yeah for sure. But I figured it was still worth correcting the misinformation since this came up in my Google search.

Answer (score 4):

No, the sorting is not based on first character or length. Alphabetical or better to put it as lexicographical ordering are done in the following way,

In C++ the comparison function would look like this,

```
bool operator<(const string &a, const string &b){
    int l = min(a.size(),b.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        if( a[i] > b[i]) return false; // a is greater than b
        if( b[i] > a[i]) return true;  // b is greater than a
    }
    if ( a.size() > l) return false;   // a is greater than b
    return true;                       // b is greater than a
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*Every* sorting algorithm works, if provided correct *comparison* function.

Just make sure the comparison between elements compares the whole strings instead of looking at only the 1st character when you implement your favorite sorting algorithm or call your sorting library function of choice.

Answer (score 1):

As you already mentioned the only difference between sorting Strings instead of numbers is the `compare` method used by nearly all sorting algorithms (Radix-sort, bucket-sort are exceptions).
Most times one of the fastest sorting algorithms is quick-sort.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to implement comparing function which *any* sort algorithm can use. In that compare function you will compare whole words, letter by letter, as you need it.

Comment: Implementing a comparison for strings is not something I’d recommend. Except to very detail-oriented people that need a hobby for the upcoming years. Use the ones your runtime already has – Vilx has listed some of the gotchas, and not even started to talk about locale-dependencies that may or may not be important for your application.